# UIButton image not resizing - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am creating a custom button with a png image as I have done hundreds of times before.

But for some reason, this time the image isn't scaling with the button size.

```
func constructInfoViewBtns() {
    let buttonsView = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 90, self.infoView!.frame.width, 90))

    let playPauseBtn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
    let playPauseBtnImg : UIImage = UIImage(named: "pauseBtn")!
    playPauseBtn.setImage(playPauseBtnImg, forState: .Normal)
    playPauseBtn.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    playPauseBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 55, 55)
    playPauseBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    playPauseBtn.center = CGPointMake(buttonsView.frame.width/2, buttonsView.frame.height/2)
    playPauseBtn.addTarget(self, action: "playPauseTrack:", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
    self.playPauseBtn = playPauseBtn

    buttonsView.addSubview(self.playPauseBtn!)

    self.infoView!.addSubview(buttonsView)

}
```

What I get is a blue box where the button image is smaller than the button's frame. Like it's padded or something...

Comment: Try Setting the image as Button's Background image. @broderickga

Comment: may be image size is bigger than button frame

Answer (score 1):

add this and try

```
playPauseBtn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(25,25,25,25)
```

Comment: how would this help?